# Maya bakepivot on keyrelease

Tags: maya, mel

In Maya 2018 I'm trying to do a script that replaces the hotkey <kbd>D</kbd> for orienting the pivot with one that does the same thing and but also automatically bakes the pivot on release. 
So I'm leaving the onpress command of the hotkey as normal but on release I do,

```
ctxEditMode -buttonUp;
BakeCustomPivot;
```

except I get an Error:

```
Invalid object or value: BakeCustomPivot //
```

I also tried doing this instead:

```
EnterEditModeRelease
BakeCustomPivot;
```

in the script editor I see that `BakeCustomPivot;` is fired before `ctxEditMode -buttonUp;` and the pivot isn't baked.

Any way to do this?